# Blue screen while formatting in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have a laptop which is **ASUS X402C** and I have a bootable usb drive with Windows 10 OS but when I try to format it, blue screen of death keeps on popping and suggests recovery options yet <kbd>F8</kbd> and the number options doesn't work.

It keeps on prompting random errors like `ntoskrnl.exe is missing or corrupt` and sometimes `corrupt  winload.exe` as well.

**Edit:** I'm unable to boot in safe mode as well because I guess I've deleted all the partition of my machine. In my previous installation I've reached the `Copying files` part then goes to blue screen again.

Comment: Probably the HDD is in its last legs. I would use a third-party bootable tool to check it, or a live Linux distro.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia do you have any suggestions for 3rd party tool or linux distro? I'm downloading Ubuntu Desktop at the moment to try if it will work.

Comment: Ubuntu and derivatives include Disks which is enough to perform SMART tests. Select the drive and ctrl+S (or the hamburger icon > SMART Data&Self-Tests...). The short test *should* shows errors but if not do the extended, this takes a a very long time.